# How to fetch RDS instance based on a particular tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

i tried this command it is list the rds instance only
aws rds describe-db-instances 
--query 'DBInstances[*].[DBName,DBInstanceIdentifier]' --output table

fetch RDS instance based on a particular tag

can anyone help me out for this

Comment: It would help if you included the tag, how it is formatted, what output you got, what output you expected, and other things you tried. There is a resource tagging api that may help. Something like [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2427#issuecomment-542499231).